# tensorflow can't handle my sample correctly in linear regression

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is a very simple linear regression algorithm from the sample. It works OK. The target function is y=1-x.

```
sess.run(init)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x:[1,2,3,4,-3], y:[0,-1,-2,-3,4]})
  curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, cost], {x:[1,2,3,4,-3], y:[0,-1,-2,-3,4]})
  print("W, b, cost: ", curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss)
```

But if I add x=35, and y=-34, the returned cost becomes very large:

```
('W, b, cost: ', array([ -1.27068623e+36], dtype=float32), array([ -4.23763612e+34], dtype=float32), inf)
('W, b, cost: ', array([  1.40919235e+36], dtype=float32), array([  4.69954423e+34], dtype=float32), inf)
('W, b, cost: ', array([ -1.56279610e+36], dtype=float32), array([ -5.21179788e+34], dtype=float32), inf)
('W, b, cost: ', array([  1.73314268e+36], dtype=float32), array([  5.77989253e+34], dtype=float32), inf)
('W, b, cost: ', array([-inf], dtype=float32), array([ -6.40990497e+34], dtype=float32), inf)
('W, b, cost: ', array([ nan], dtype=float32), array([ nan], dtype=float32), nan)
('W, b, cost: ', array([ nan], dtype=float32), array([ nan], dtype=float32), nan)
('W, b, cost: ', array([ nan], dtype=float32), array([ nan], dtype=float32), nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i figured out. the learning rate is too large in this case, change to 0.001 seems working.
so learning rate has to be chosen related to the training data, e.g. 0.01 for x<10, 0.001 for x<30,...